# How to show the row where QPushButton is clicked in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I would like to delete row where `QPushButton` is clicked how it is possible to I think it is reasonable to use slots but how to do it don't know , if you have any ideas how to get a row of selected button please share, thanks.

It is my table

[image]

It is a code where i add rows to my QTableWidget

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    for(int i = 0; i<20;i++)
        ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
    QVector<QString>vec;
    vec<<"first"<<"sec"<<"third"<<"for"<<"fif"<<"first"<<"sec"
      <<"third"<<"for"<<"fif";
    vec<<"first"<<"sec"<<"third"<<"for"<<"fif"<<"first"<<"sec"
      <<"third"<<"for"<<"fif";
    for(int i = 0; i<ui->tableWidget->rowCount();i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<ui->tableWidget->columnCount();j++)
        {
            if(j == 0)
            {
                QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget();
                QPushButton* btn_edit = new QPushButton();
                btn_edit->setText("Remove");
                QHBoxLayout* pLayout = new QHBoxLayout(pWidget);
                pLayout->addWidget(btn_edit);
                pLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
                pLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                pWidget->setLayout(pLayout);
                ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(i, j, pWidget);
                continue;

            }
            QTableWidgetItem*item = new QTableWidgetItem(vec[i]);
            item->setFlags(item->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsEditable);
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, j, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This task can be solved using the [`removeRow()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#removeRow) method but before we must get the row. First of all we will connect all the buttons to a slot inside the loop as shown below:

***.h**

```
private slots:
    void onClicked();
```

***.cpp**

```
[...]
QPushButton* btn_edit = new QPushButton();
btn_edit->setText("Remove");
connect(btn_edit, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onClicked);
[...]
```

In the slot we can get the button that emits the signal through the [`sender()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) method, then we get `QWidget` parent (created with the name pWidget), this is the widget that is added to the `QTableWidget` and its position is relative to it, then we use the method [`indexAt()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt) to get the `QModelIndex` associated with the cell, and this has the information of the row through the method [`row()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#row). All of the above is implemented in the following lines:

```
void MainWindow::onClicked()
{
    QWidget *w = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(sender()->parent());
    if(w){
        int row = ui->tableWidget->indexAt(w->pos()).row();
        ui->tableWidget->removeRow(row);
        ui->tableWidget->setCurrentCell(0, 0);
    }
}
```

*Note:* The [`setCurrentCell()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setCurrentCell) method is used to set the focus since the last cell that has it has been deleted.

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/46329431-how-to-show-the-row-where-qpushbutton-is-clicked-in-qtablewidget).

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating QPushButton just add :

```
    btn_delete = new QPushButton("Remove", ui->tableWidget);
    btn_delete->setObjectName(QString("%1").arg(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()));

    connect(btn_delete, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,    SLOT(CellButtonDeleteClicked()));
```

And create function CellButtonDeleteClicked()

```
     void CellButtonDeleteClicked()
     {

      //   by this line I can get the sender of signal
      QPushButton *pb = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(QObject::sender());

      int row = pb->objectName().toInt();
      ui->tableWidget->removeRow(row);
     }
```