# how to get row number after comboBox item in QTableWidget in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I would like to get a number of a QTableWidget row after selecting some topic in comboBox how it is possible to get the row, [image]thanks.

```
void MainWindow::metto_stringa(int i)
{
    QWidget *w = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(sender()->parent());
    if(w)
    {
        int row = ui->tableWidget->indexAt(w->pos()).row();
        ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::number( row ));
    }
    // ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::number( i ));
}
```

---

```
else if(i == 3)
{
     // ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(ui->tableWidget->rowCount(), i, "");
      QString s = "Normal";
      QComboBox *combo = new QComboBox;
      combo->addItem("Below normal");
      combo->addItem("Normal");
      combo->addItem("Above normal");
      combo->addItem("High");
      combo->addItem("Real time");
      connect(combo,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),this,
      SLOT(metto_stringa(int)));
      ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1,  i,combo);
      /*  ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,4,combo);
      QTableWidgetItem*item = new QTableWidgetItem(s);
      item->setFlags(item->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsEditable);
      ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1, i, 
      item);*/
      continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should not use the parent of the `QComboBox`, you must use the same `sender()`

```
void MainWindow::metto_stringa(int index)
{
    QWidget *w = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(sender());
    if(w)
    {
        int row = ui->tableWidget->indexAt(w->pos()).row();
        ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::number(row));
    }
}
```

In the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329431/how-to-show-the-row-where-qpushbutton-is-clicked-in-qtablewidget) I answered before I commented that you must access the widget that you use in the `setCellWidget()` function, in the previous case the widget had the following form:

```
QWidget <--- QPushButton
parent()     sender()
```

ie you owe to that widget so we take advantage of `sender()` and `parent()` in the previous case. In the current case `QComboBox` is added directly.

Comment: eyllanesc, thanks for your idea but it doesnt works for me it writes -1 in qlineEdit maybe you know how it is possible to use currentRow() for it?

Comment: Are you sure ?, I just tried it and I do not get the correct row

Comment: `currentRow()` does not work since this returns the row that has been selected and in case you use `setCellWidget()` the selection is not transmitted to the table.

Comment: Check my answer, you have to change: `QWidget *w = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(sender()->parent());` to `QWidget *w = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(sender());`

Comment: You have not made this change, please correct it and if it works do not forget to mark my answer as correct.